# Expand $\sqrt{x(1-x)}$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I am trying to expand $\sqrt{x(1-x)}$ in order to find the order of it as $x\to0$.

Using Taylor expansion to find the derivative of the equation as $x\to0$ gives each item $0$.

Then how do we expand it? Thanks,

Comment: Consider taking the Taylor Expansion of $(1-x)^{1/2}$ term and then multiplying each term of the expansion by $x^{1/2}$.

Comment: This is brilliant! :)

Comment: Yes, in steps : $$x(1-x)^{1/2}$$   
        $$x..(1-x)^{1/2}$$
$$x.......(1-x)^{1/2}$$
$$x.................(1-x)^{1/2}$$
$$x........................(1-x)^{1/2}$$

Do you want more?

Comment: The graph of the function is a semicircle that meets the $x$-axis at right angles at $x=0$ and $x=1$. Does this tell you what you want about its behavior near $x=0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general
$$\lim_{x \to 0} (1+x)^{\alpha} = 1 + \binom{\alpha}{1} x + \binom{\alpha}{2} x^2 + \binom{\alpha}{3} x^3 + \ldots = \sum_{i = 0}^{n} \binom{\alpha}{i} x^{i} + O(x^n)$$
thus as $x \to 0$
\begin{align}
\sqrt{x(1+x)}&=\sqrt{x} \cdot \sqrt{1+x} \\
&=x^{1/2} \cdot (1+x)^{1/2}\\
&=x^{1/2} \cdot \left( \sum_{i = 0}^{n} \binom{\frac{1}{2}}{i} x^{i} + O(x^n) \right) \\
&=x^{1/2} \cdot \left( 1 + \frac{x}{2} -  \frac{x^2}{8} + \ldots \right)
\end{align}
so, as $x \to 0$
\begin{align}
\sqrt{x(1-x)}&=\sqrt{x} \cdot \sqrt{1-x} \\
&=x^{1/2} \cdot (1-x)^{1/2}\\
&=x^{1/2} \cdot \left( \sum_{i = 0}^{n} \binom{\frac{1}{2}}{i} (-x)^{i} + O(x^n) \right) \\
&=x^{1/2} \cdot \left( 1 - \frac{x}{2} + \frac{x^2}{8} + \ldots \right)
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

my answer:

$\sqrt{x(1-x)}$

$=x^{1/2}(1-x)^{1/2}$

expand for $x\to 0$,

$=x^{1/2}(1+\frac 12(-x)+\frac{\frac12(1-\frac{1}{2})}{2!}(-x)^2+...........)$

$=x^{1/2}-\frac 12x^{3/2}-\frac{1}{8}x^{5/2}+...........$

Comment: The OP asked for a Taylor expansion. You did not give one, since your expression has fractional exponents. If there is a way to use your expression to find its order, please explain.

Answer (score 1):

Find the derivatives of $$f(x)=\sqrt{1-x}$$
$$=\sqrt{1-0}+\frac{\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sqrt{1-x}\right)\left(0\right)}{1!}x+\frac{\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\left(\sqrt{1-x}\right)\left(0\right)}{2!}x^2+\frac{\frac{d^3}{dx^3}\left(\sqrt{1-x}\right)\left(0\right)}{3!}x^3+\ldots \:$$
Then

$\sqrt{1-0}\quad :\quad 1$

$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sqrt{1-x}\right)\left(0\right)\quad :\quad -\frac{1}{2}$

$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\left(\sqrt{1-x}\right)\left(0\right)\quad :\quad -\frac{1}{4}$

$\frac{d^3}{dx^3}\left(\sqrt{1-x}\right)\left(0\right)\quad :\quad -\frac{3}{8}$

$\frac{d^4}{dx^4}\left(\sqrt{1-x}\right)\left(0\right)\quad :\quad -\frac{15}{16}$

So
$$=1+\frac{-\frac{1}{2}}{1!}x+\frac{-\frac{1}{4}}{2!}x^2+\frac{-\frac{3}{8}}{3!}x^3+\frac{-\frac{15}{16}}{4!}x^4+\ldots $$

Answer (score 0):

As Aditya Agarwal said:

$\sqrt{x(1+x)}=x^{1/2}(1-x/2+...)$

Comment: how did you get that?